# Grouping function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, average

I'm fairly new to Excel and can't find how to formulate my question, so sorry if this has been asked before.

The data I have contains information on literacy, employment and income per hour for diferent towns of different counties as shown in the link below. Is there a way I can group all the towns together and obtain the average of each rate I am working on?

[image]

Comment: Use a Pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott Craner suggested in the comments you could use a pivot table.

In the English (UK) version of Excel this would be done by selecting the data, going to Insert and clciking on Pivot Table.

In the Pivot Table Fields move Town into the Rows area, and the Literacy Rate, Income per Hour and Employment Rate field into the Values section. Then adjust the Value Fields Setting from SUM (which is the default) to AVERAGE.

Here's a quick screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Pivot Tbale setup]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2007 or later, you can use the `AVERAGEIFS` function.

I'll assume that the data in your question starts in the range A1:E16. Enter this formula in cell F2 and copy it to the range F2:H16.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$16,$B$2:$B$16,$B2)
```

What the formula does in cell F2 is average all the cells in column C where the value in column B is the same as B2.